# html5 video disable pausing when clicked on video viewing area

Tags: html, html5-video

As the title explains,

I need to disable pausing when clicked on the video viewing area, since i'm trying to attach other events when clicked on that area.

I tried using this videojs.com But found no solution

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way - just add this to css file:

```
.video-js.vjs-playing .vjs-tech {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in video.dev.js (version 4.1) line 3399 comment function body

```
// OnClick - Toggle between play and pause
vjs.PlayToggle.prototype.onClick = function(){
  /*if (this.player_.paused()) {
    this.player_.play();
  } else {
    this.player_.pause();
  }*/
};
```

in video.js line 80 column 403 its the same function , comment function body

```
function(){/*this.a.controls()&&(this.a.paused()?this.a.play():this.a.pause())*/}
```

Comment: While this question helped me to find my solution it didn't quite solve this problem in version 4.3.0 the same code is found on line 84 and looks like this:
`u.r.prototype.p=function(a){0===a.button&&this.K().controls()&&(this.K().paused()?this.K().play():this.K().pause())};`

but commented out looks like this:
    `u.r.prototype.p=function(a){/*0===a.button&&this.K().controls()&&(this.K().paused()?this.K().play():this.K().pause())*/};`

Comment: The PlayToggle object is actually the little pause/play arrow on the bottom left of the control bars, not the video viewing area.

Comment: @JustinMcDonald 
Please read question before, then look at date of answer. ))
Thanks for down vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind editing the videojs files directly you can either set the CSS for bigPlayButton to none instead of block, or comment out the following:

```
// Make a click on the video act as a play button 
this.activateElement(this.video, "playToggle");
```

and this behaviour will be gone.

Comment: its not about the initial playback. After the video starts playing, when a user clicks it should not pause. More over i could not find this line in video.js file

Comment: Yep, this is for when you click on the video.
Disable the bigPlayButton component and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on Ashot his answer for the solution on Video JS 4.6.3, but my reputation is not high enough yet.

MrHunter provided the answer for Video JS 4.3. 
In version 4.6.3 the same code is on line 99 of the file video.js and looks like this:

```
function(a){0===a.button&&this.m().controls()&&(this.m().paused()?this.m().play():this.m().pause())};
```

After commented out it looks like this:

```
function(a){/*0===a.button&&this.m().controls()&&(this.m().paused()?this.m().play():this.m().pause())*/};
```

This worked perfectly for me. Thanks to Ashot and MrHunter for leading me to the solution on the newest version of Video JS!

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to prevent pause on click on the video,
Just add these 2 lines in the script.**

```
var videoEle = document.getElementById("videoTagId");
videoEle.onpause = () => { videoEle.play(); }
```